# ValueError 1: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions

Tags: pyspark

In the below code :

```
retail_sales_transaction = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="conform_main_mobconv",
    table_name="retail_sales_transaction"
)

df_retail_sales_transaction= (retail_sales_transaction.toDF().filter((f.col('dh_audit_source_system_id')=='SRC_JDAESO') & (f.col('country_code') in ('AU','NZ')))) \
.select("transaction_id","transaction_key","transaction_timestamp","personnel_key","retail_site_id","personnel_role","country_code","business_week","dh_audit_start_timestamp")
```

Getting error while running above statement :
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Comment: I think the issue is in the `in` clause. Try using `OR` or `expr` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `in` try using `.isin`

```
f.col('country_code').isin('AU','NZ')
```